VLC Saved m3u8 File Plays Multiple Audio Tracks Simultaneously
I am trying to download a streaming video to my computer so that I can watch it when offline. I am able to download it and convert to mp4, but the audio is playing multiple languages simultaneously (i.e., English and Spanish).
The source is m3u8 video and I'm using VLC Media Player 3.0 on Mac. Steps are pretty well known:

File > Open Network
URL: m3u8 file path
Stream Output: selected
Settings: Save to file
Encapsulation Method: MPEG 4

I tried fiddling with the Transcoding Options: Audio > Channels, but it didn't make any difference.

On the site where the video is hosted, you can of course choose from a couple languages. I have selected English. That is all I hear when viewing on the site. That is the m3u8 file path that I copied.
Once the file is downloaded and converted with VLC, I play the mp4 back with QuickTime Player. I hear both English and Spanish tracks at the same time. When I go the View > Languages there are no options displayed to adjust it in the player.
Thanks for any suggestions. I am also open to using something other than VLC, but this seems like the best option.

A file in m3u8 or m3u format is just a text file, "a UTF-8 encoded playlist." It contains no video or audio data, only the location of that resource.
Feel free to open it in a text editor, such as Notepad, Kate, or Notepad++ and edit to remove unwanted audio tracks.
In the example below, it points to the location of the mp3 audio tracks in the same folder as that m3u file. If one line were to be deleted, e.g., WTK1-01.mp3, that audio file would not be played.


Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure how this would work. I can download the m3u8 file and edit it, but the file paths are all relative so they won't have access to the source. Opening the original or edited m3u8 file with VLC produces nothing, as it isn't streaming the associated content (i.e., video or audio).
